# Python Sparql Quering A Local File

Tags: python, rdf, sparql, ontology

I have the following code which I use to print whole of my ontology. However, how can i perform some sparql with it, query  and then print the resulting graph?

```
g = Graph()
g.parse('PLAYERS3.owl')
for s,p,o in g:
    print s
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This code should do the trick:

```
import rdflib
from rdflib import Graph

rdflib.plugin.register('sparql', rdflib.query.Processor,
                       'rdfextras.sparql.processor', 'Processor')
rdflib.plugin.register('sparql', rdflib.query.Result,
                       'rdfextras.sparql.query', 'SPARQLQueryResult')
g = Graph()
g.parse('PLAYERS3.owl')

query = """
SELECT * WHERE {
        ?s ?p ?o .
}
"""
for row in g.query(query):
    print row
```